# Hosting full stack app in Azure Static Web Apps build issues

Tags: azure, vue.js, hosting, vite, azure-static-web-app

I've been banging my head against this issue with no luck for a solid week so any suggestions would be super appreciated! I'm building a catalog website for a client. I have a server and DB run through Azure SQL and then my frontend is all vue.js compiled with Vite. I have a very simple backend written with express/node that I can interact with locally without any issues.

Where I'm having trouble is when I actually go to build my app (I chose to do the auto-build with github Actions). The frontend code loads fine but it doesn't look like my backend app is ever actually being started. I'm not getting any of my logs from my server/api files and all of my attempts to hit my endpoints come back as connection refused.

I've tried changing my api_start_command to run my server through node but that just starts the server and never closes it so it can't move on with the deployment. I've also tried starting it through vite but it looks like my api/server files aren't even there after I build. I've gone through all of the microsoft docs for static web apps and connecting apis and changed everything I can think of in my build settings. I've also tried this with an Azure Web App with the same results.

I'm not well-versed enough in deployment through azure to be able to make sense of where my problem is actually coming from. I suspect that it's either the vite config file or my set up in itself. Do I need to make a separate app just for the backend? If so, would I need to put that in its own repo? For reference I'll include my vite config code and my yaml workflow below.

Vite.config

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
vue(),
],
build: {
rollupOptions: {
plugins: [
copy({
targets: [
{ src: 'server.js', dest: 'dist' },
{ src: 'api.js', dest: 'dist' },
],
hook: 'writeBundle'
}),
]
}
},
resolve: {
alias: {
'@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
}
}
})
```

github actions workflow yaml

```
name: Deploy web app to Azure Static Web Apps
env:
APP_LOCATION: "/evo" # location of your client code
API_LOCATION: "/evo" # location of your api source code - optional
OUTPUT_LOCATION: "dist" # location of client code build output
DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
DB_PASS: ${{ secrets.DB_PASS }}
on:
push:
branches:
- main
pull_request:
types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
branches:
- main
permissions:
issues: write
contents: read
pull-requests: write
jobs:
build_and_deploy:
if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
name: Build and Deploy
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
with:
submodules: true
- name: Build And Deploy
uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@1a947af9992250f3bc2e68ad0754c0b0c11566c9
with:
azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_MANGO_PEBBLE_0E2297810 }}
repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
action: "upload"
app_location: ${{ env.APP_LOCATION }}
api_location: ${{ env.API_LOCATION }}
output_location: ${{ env.OUTPUT_LOCATION }}

close_pull_request:
if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
name: Close Pull Request
steps:
- name: Close Pull Request
uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@1a947af9992250f3bc2e68ad0754c0b0c11566c9
with:
azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_MANGO_PEBBLE_0E2297810 }}
action: "close"
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Update from comments: here is my backend code as well!

Api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client
const port = process.env.PORT || 1433;
const pool = require('./server'); // Import the database connection pool

app.use(express.json());

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Get All Categories
app.get('/api/data/categories', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const result = await request.query('SELECT * FROM categories2');
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Get Parent Categories
app.get('/api/data/categories/parents', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const result = await request.query('SELECT * FROM categories2 WHERE parentCategory = 1');
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Get Subcategories by Category
app.get('/api/data/categories/:parent', async (req, res) => {
  const { parent } = req.params; // Retrieve the parent parameter from the URL
  try {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const query = `SELECT * FROM categories2 WHERE parentId = @parent`; // Use a parameterized query to filter by parent
    request.input('parent', sql.NVarChar, parent);
    const result = await request.query(query);
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Get All Products
app.get(`/api/data/products`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const result = await request.query('SELECT * FROM products');
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Get Products by Category
app.get('/api/data/products/:category', async (req, res) => {
  const { category } = req.params; // Retrieve the category parameter from the URL
  try {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const query = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category_ID = @category`; // Use a parameterized query to filter by category
    request.input('category', sql.NVarChar, category);
    const result = await request.query(query);
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Get Product by Part Number
app.get('/api/data/product/:partNum', async (req, res) => {
  const { partNum } = req.params; // Retrieve the category parameter from the URL
  try {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    console.log(request);
    const query = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE Part_Number = @partNum`; // Use a parameterized query to filter by category
    console.log(query);
    request.input('partNum', sql.NVarChar, partNum);
    const result = await request.query(query);
    if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
      res.json(result.recordset); // Return the results if any are found
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ error: 'Product not found' }); // Return 404 if no product is found
    }  
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client
var test = require('dotenv').config();

var config = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  server: process.env.SERVER_NAME,
  database: 'EvoDB'
}

// Create a pool of database connections
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

// Connect to the database
pool.connect()
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to SQL Server'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Database connection error:', err));

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: Looking at the github workflow file, you are only deploying the front end. do you deploy the backend separately ? Is it out of the box backend from static website ?

Comment: @user13618009 please your backend code

Comment: @Thomas I thought the api_location would be to deploy the back end? They're in the same root folder, do I need to make a separate folder just for my server and api with its own package.json? I guess that would explain why it isn't being built in vite correctly.

Comment: @Sampath Updated the question with my backend code!

Comment: Actually, API location is for the azure function [app](https://github.com/marcduiker/staticwebapp-vue-vite/tree/main/api) with .js. You used back end URL in front end. So the back end and front end should be deployed separately.

Comment: have you check backend options for static websites: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-overview ?

Comment: out of the box solution uses a managed function app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=vanilla-javascript. otherwise you can check other hosting options from previous comment/link

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I had been through all of those docs already and it looks like I'm just going to have to rewrite my express app as an Azure Functions app if I want it to play nicely in production. I was hoping to avoid that since it seems super complex but I don't think there's an easier solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah the integrated azure function solution should be easy tho, just need to do some rewrite i guess

Answer (score 0):

I followed this  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-vue?pivots=github)  for the deployment of a Vue app on Azure Static Web Apps.

- The sample code below is for a Vue app with an API endpoint. The code below is for Vue.js which fetches data from a backend API.

`App.vue`

```java
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Data from Backend</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in data" :key="item.ID">
        {{ item.Name }} - Age: {{ item.Age }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:7071/api/getTitleFromApi');
        this.data = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

- Create an API with  [Azure Function](https://github.com/marcduiker/staticwebapp-vue-vite/tree/main/api).
- Observe the project  [structure](https://i.imgur.com/ZygFJup.png)  while creating a function app.
- Replace the below code in the function app with an API endpoint.
- Below is the Azure Functions code that connects to an Azure SQL Database, performs a simple query, and acts as an API.

```java
const sql = require('mssql');
const cors = require('cors')(); // Enable CORS for all origins

const config = {
  server: 'Azure Sql server',
  database: 'Azure Sql Database',
  user: 'User Name',
  password: 'password',
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: false,
    connectTimeout: 30000,
  },
};

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  // Enable CORS for the function
  cors(context.req, context.res, () => {});

  const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

  try {
    await pool.connect();
    context.log('Connected to SQL Server');

    
    const result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable]');

    
    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      body: result.recordset,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Allow requests from any origin
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET', // Specify the allowed methods
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    context.log.error('Database connection error:', err);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: 'Internal Server Error',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Allow requests from any origin
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET', // Specify the allowed methods
      },
    };
  } finally {
    if (pool.connected) {
      await pool.close();
      context.log('Closed SQL Server connection');
    }
  }
};
```

**Local:**
[image]

[image]

**Yml:**

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths-ignore:
      - '**/*.md'
      - 'img/*.png'
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
    paths-ignore:
      - '**/*.md'
      - 'img/*.png'

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BRAVE_WATER_026F39A03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          app_build_command: "npm run build"
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BRAVE_WATER_026F39A03 }}
          action: "close"
```

**Deployment status:**
[image]
**Azure:**

[image]